# Minting NFTs in Solana. with rent pay per byte is size based on ledger metadata or NFT token size like image that will be sold

Tags: storage, solana, nft

I want to create some NFT's which will be sound files.
Is the size in https://docs.solana.com/storage_rent_economics pay per byte scenario the size of the sound or size of the metadata related to the ledger ?

So is the token data stored in the ledger and this have the cost associated with it or is there only reference URL stored in the ledger and the size of rent is that URL reference plus internal data of Solana ?

I am trying work out if it is the size of the token like picture or sound then the bigger the data the bigger the rent costs.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata onchain and off-chain in solana NFTs are standardised by the metaplex protocol. Docs are here: https://docs.metaplex.com/token-metadata/v1.1.0/api

The actual on-chain struct is what you would pay in rent for as seen here in the metaplex docs and can also be confirmed in their open source github:
https://docs.metaplex.com/token-metadata/v1.1.0/specification#metadata-struct

The on-chain URI it references would then point to your off-chain json metadata defined further down on the same page linked above. This off-chain json metadata also has a uri key which would probably be where you would finally point to your sound files. The json metadata and sound files should be uploaded to a "global, permanent hard drive" such as the arweave network.

So to answer your question briefly, you will pay minimal rent costs in SOL if you don't store your sound file on-chain.